# ABP - Injecting serilog into application service for logging

Tags: asp.net, abp

I'm trying to inject serilog as a dependency into my application service, but it is not getting detected by the DI.

Error:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating TenTime.AccountService.Accounts.Commands.CreateAccount.CreateAccountCommandHandler.
 ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'TenTime.AccountService.Accounts.Commands.CreateAccount.CreateAccountCommandHandler' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger' of constructor 'Void .ctor(TenTime.AccountService.ApplicationUserManger, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions], Volo.Abp.EventBus.Distributed.IDistributedEventBus, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger)'.
```

Even though I'm registering the logger in my HttpApi.Host layer:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        context.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
            loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
        });
```

Comment: Did you use a  ABP module template ?

Comment: Please make sure you include a full stack trace in your question, and indicate which line of your code is throwing the exception. I suspect you just have namespace confusion between Serilog and Microsoft's logger, since they both use an interface called ILogger. That'd be easier to say with confidence if you provided a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The serilog is already integrated to the ABP templates and this is the default configuration for it in the [`Program.cs`](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.HttpApi.Host/Program.cs):

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
#if DEBUG
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
#else
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
#endif
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Async(c => c.File("Logs/logs.txt"))
            .WriteTo.Async(c => c.Console())
            .CreateLogger();  //Configuration

        try
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Host.AddAppSettingsSecretsJson()
                .UseAutofac()
                .UseSerilog(); // -> Registration
            await builder.AddApplicationAsync<MyProjectNameHttpApiHostModule>();
            var app = builder.Build();
            await app.InitializeApplicationAsync();
            await app.RunAsync();
            return 0;
        }
        // Removed for brevity
```

It is already using `Serilog.Sinks.Async`.

ABP uses .NET logging abstraction. To use the logger, you can simply inject the `ILogger<TCategory>` or the `ILoggerFactory` and create it yourself. See [Logging in .NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).